# bootstrap 4 beta scrollspy not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, scrollspy

I realize this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46120688/scrollspy-not-working-bootstrap-4-beta), but the answer given there isn't using the scrollspy plug in but is instead writing out all of the javascript to highlight active links on scroll.

I've gone through pretty much all other iterations of this question that I could find but my code looks the same as in the solutions given so I'm not sure of the problem. (most other questions are also not for bootstrap 4 beta but rather earlier versions)

I'm using the javascript file from [this scrolling nav template](https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-scrolling-nav) to scroll down to a section when you click a link. This works, so the links are all connected to the sections by their ID's properly.

The template's `JS` file has the `JS` to activate scrollspy built in, but it's not working for me.

The body's position is set as relative. 
The `jQuery.js` file is placed before the before the `bootstrap.js` file.

I've also tried the method of applying the `data-spy` and `data-target` to the `body` tag.

I have styled the `.active` class but before and after doing this, I've inspected my page in chrome, and the `.active` class is not being applied to the links as you scroll so I don't think the problem is related to `CSS`.

Here is the javascript:

```
$('body').scrollspy({
    target: '#mainNav',
    offset: 0
  });
```

and the code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav" style="margin-bottom:0;padding-bottom:0;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top"><img class="img-fluid" src="backgroundimages/logoSmall.png"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item navMenuBox">
        <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#howto" style="display:block;">How to Use</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item navMenuBox">
        <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#Mappy" style="display:block;">Map</a>
      </li>
        <li class="nav-item navMenuBox">
        <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about" style="display:block;">About</a>
      </li>
        <li class="nav-item navMenuBox">
        <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact" style="display:block;">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO. to fix this I realized that the spyscroll is mainly dependent on having either `navbar-dark` or `navbar-light` applied to your `navbar`. It would've been very helpful if this was in the documentation!
Even though I had `navbar-dark` applied, since I'd assumed the `.active` state was connected to the `nav-links` or `nav-items`, I had styled the `nav-links`, causing the `.active` state to not work.
To fix my issue I applied my custom styles to the `.navbar-dark li a`, and my custom active state to

```
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.show,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active
```

(this was pulled from the bootstrap css, I searched through it to figure out how the `.active` was being styled & just copy/pasted these classes into my custom `CSS` document)

Hope this helps someone else with a similar problem!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided, it's difficult to discern where the actual issue is coming from. My guess is that you're missing a dependency from the scrolling nav template from github, but I could be wrong.

If you haven't included the `jQuery.easing` from their package.json file, that could be the issue.

I've taken the code you were using and put it into a codepen project, and was able to make it work using `jQuery 3.2.1` and `jQuery-easing 1.4.1`.

You can view it [here](https://codepen.io/cowanjt/pen/zEGYLQ).

Comment: I have jQuery easing included, it's necessary for the scrolling trigger. Your example isn't working for me? It animates the scrolling to the section when you click the link (which I also was able to get to work) but the links don't change states as you scroll to indicate you're on that section (the scrollspy bit)

Comment: Okay. There were some issues with different versions of jQuery being added. You can view it [here](https://codepen.io/cowanjt/pen/zEGYLQ).

Comment: What exactly did you change? when I look at both of your examples, the javascript files plugged in are the same, and I checked and I'm using the same versions of all the files as you. As far as I can see my code is the same as yours

Comment: Just to clarify, the issues with different versions of jQuery being added were in my project when I tried to recreate yours. I only changed the `offset` of the `scrollspy` function, but that's so the `scrollspy` would line up correctly with the structure of my example. I also took out some inline styling you had, but that's irrelevant. 

If it's not your code, then it's something in your environment, but before I would rule out your code, see if you can create a working codepen with your code.

Comment: sooo here's a codepen where I tried to make it work.. and it isn't working :/ the scroll trigger is still working but not the scrollspy. [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rGVOjq) When I paste in your nav code from your codepen it still doesn't work. I am stumped.

Comment: [here's another] (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BwNovm) where the divs with the id's have no content, basically the same as yours. it's still not working!!

Comment: i plugged both our code into this site and there are no consequential differences whatsoever. [link](https://www.diffchecker.com/3aMXCPpP)

Comment: Add the `navbar-dark` or `navbar-light` class to your nav element.

Comment: yup. realized that was the issue, I had navbar-dark applied in my document but had added styles to the nav-links that made it not work. Finally fixed it! you'd think in the documentation somewhere they'd mention that navbar-dark or light are necessary for the scrollspy to work. Thanks for all your help!!!